# Why is "%s" format specifier working even for a character array without `\0` & printing all its elements at once?

Tags: c, string, null-terminated, null-character

Look at the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[7]={'E','R','I','C'};
    printf("%s",name);
}
```

It outputs the entire `name` **ERIC**.Why is it so?Isn't `%s` supposed to work only if we initialize the character array `name` as follows:

```
    char name[7]={'E','R','I','C','\0'};   //With NULL terminator
```

I am not considering the following as this obviously assumes a null-terminated character array:

```
   char name[7]="ERIC"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the c11 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> (6.7.9.21)
>   If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.
>
> (6.7.9.10)
>   If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;

Thus, when you init an array like this:

```
char name[7]={'E','R','I','C'};
```

It is as same as:

```
char name[7]={'E','R','I','C', 0, 0, 0};
```

So `name` is still null-terminated.

Comment: Why did H2CO3 delete his answer?Anyways, do you mean to say  in clear and unambiguous words based on the standard that it is safe as long as the size of the array is  at least **one** more than the intended number of characters we want to initialize it with?

Comment: Seems like Taiwan is catching up with Hungary...LOL...(H2CO3 is Hungarian)

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I deleted my answer because it was wrong :) Seems scary that authority has **this much** effect on voting - "just because he has 69k rep, he must be right", and I've got three upvotes for an incorrect answer... >.<

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, I was surprised as I am not used to see you giving wrong answers.Also, you got 3 vote ups for that.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I don't tend to give wrong answers :) This was an exception (actually, what I've written wasn't wrong in itself, it's just that it was **not** the answer to your question.)

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Yes, I mean to say what you said at the first comment.

Comment: @phoxis Perhaps he *is* a bot, in which case he just passed the Turing test.

Comment: @phoxis He is not a bot,he's Hungarian.I had asked him.

Comment: Sorry for posting off topic comments, but this reminded me the dialogue from Rocky IV "You see? You see? He's not a machine, he's a man, he's a man!"

Answer (score 2):

From C99 Section 7.21.6.1 Paragraph 8 `%s` specifier

> If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to
>   the initial element of an array of character type. **Characters from
>   the array are written up to (but not including) the terminating null
>   character**. If the precision is specified, no more than that many bytes
>   are written. If the precision is not specified or is greater than the
>   size of the array, the array shall contain a null character.

Therefore if you have a pointer to a `char *` which you print using `printf` it will print until a `\0` is not found.

Also

`char name[7]={'E','R','I','C'};` is `` `\0' `` terminated in this case because the length of the array is 7 but only 4 of locations are initialized which will result in the other remaining locations to be initialized to 0. Check johnchen902's answer for more.

Comment: Only global variables are  guaranteed to be zero-filled.

Comment: I have not repeated the @johnchen902's quotes. See here "... the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration".